# Trouble referencing movieClips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, button, dynamic

I am working on a flash project that dynamically generates navigation from an XML. For now I am trying to get it to work with arrays so that I can adapt it to xml once I know the logic works. I am new to as3 and learning has been a tiny bit bumpy. I have been searching for a solution to this but many of the examples I have seen have either been too simple to answer my question or too complex to understand since I am on the new side. This is the code I am working with.

```
var clientList:Array = new Array("Client1","Client2","Client3","Client4","Client5","Client6","Client7","Client8","Client9","Client10","Client11","Client12","Client13","Client14","Client15");
for each (var cName in clientList){
    var newClientBtn:btnClientNav = new btnClientNav();
    newClientBtn.x = workX;
    newClientBtn.y = workY;
    workY += newClientBtn.height;
    newClientBtn.mcClientName.text = cName;
    lContent.mcWork.addChild(newClientBtn.name);
    trace(newClientBtn);
}
```

I can't fingure out how to properly refernce the dynamically created clips. I have a dynamic text box in the button but can't figure out how to reference it properly to change it, then my next issue will be referencing the buttons to make rollover and click code. I know this probably something simple to fix but I have been looking at it for too long and my eyes are starting to cross.. Thank you in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: Is the btnClientNav a `MovieClip` that was exported to Actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the clips you are creating in an object you can access later?

If you want to reference a movie clip by name though, one way to do it is:

```
var referenceMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(containerMC.getChildByName(“targetMC”));
```

If it was a text field or a button you were after, I believe you would do the same but instead cast the result of getChildByName to your desired control.

I also believe you want to add the button itself as a child, not pass its name into your addChild call?

Comment: What do you mean by storing the buttons in an object? Do you mean a customer class? Wouldn't it be the same problem if they were created in a custom class? How would you reference them in the timeline. I have never written custom classes before in ActionScript. I have worked with them in objectiveC but for some reason that makes more sense to me. I am not sure when it is appropriate to use them in Flash especially when i am creating the art as movieClips.

Comment: I was thinking you can have another array in which you just assign your new movie clips to that array, so if you ever need to access your newClientBtn again, how about something like:
`var mybuttons:Array = new Array();` and in your loop `mybuttons.push(newClientBtn);`